# How to provide table name from textbox to Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I want to give table name from textbox to Linq :

```
      StudentDatabaseEntities empl = new StudentDatabaseEntities();

        var query = from g in empl.Teachers
                    where g.id == 1
                    select new
                    {
                        Teacher_Id = g.tech_id,
                        Teacher_Name = g.username,
                        Teach_password = g.password,
                        Teacher_contact = g.contact,
                        Teacher_secret = g.secret,

                        //Administrator_Id = g.Administrator.id,

                        Administrator_Name = g.Administrator.username,
                        Administrator_password=g.Administrator.password,
                        Administrator_contact=g.Administrator.contact,
                        Administrator_secret=g.Administrator.secret
                        //etc...
                    };
        dataGridView1.DataSource = query.ToList();
```

In this example I want to give table name from textbox instead of Teacher . 
Is it possible ?

Comment: Do you have different entities with the same properties? Do they have a common interface?

Answer (score 0):

You can't/it doesn't make sense to violate type safety in this way:

```
from g in myTextbox.Text
where g.id == 1
```

What are you going to write in the textbox? "empl.Teachers"?

What if I wrote "empl.Students", or "go away". What will your program do then?

If you have multiple collections of Teachers, you could do something like this:

```
var teachers = new Dictionary<string, (type of your teacher collection)>();
teachers["empl"] = empl.Teachers;
teachers["empl2"] = empl2.Teachers;

from g in teachers[myTextbox.Text]
where g.id == 1
```

And then you can write "empl" or "empl2" in your textbox.. But that doesn't really gel with your expectation of "writing the database table name in the textbox"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the same query on different types, all types that you want to use should have all properties that you use in your query.

For instance, if you want to do the same query with Students, Students should also have tech_id, username, secret etc.

Normally you would do this using inheritance / composition or Interface. Something like:

```
interface IPersonData
{
    public int tech_id {get;}
    public string username {get;}
    ...
}
class Teacher : IPersonData {...}
class Student : IPersonData {...}
```

Furthermore class `StudentDataBaseEntities` needs a function to select the proper entity based on entity type. So if you ask for "Teachers that ..." it should use empl.Teachers, and if you ask for "Students who ..." it should use empl.Students.

If you use Entity Framework, you can use class [DbContext.Set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696521(v=vs.113).aspx) for this. Otherwise you'll have to create a similar function yourself.

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> ToMyData<TSource>(this TSource source)
    where TSource : IPersonData
{
    return source
        .Where(sourceItem => sourceItem.Id == 1)
        .Select(sourceItem => new
        {
             Id = sourceItem.tech_id,
             Name = sourceItem.username,
             ...
        });
}

static IQueryable<TSource> ToMyData<TSource>(this DbContext dbContext)
     where TSource : IPersonData
{
    return dbContext.Set<TSource>().ToMyData();
}
```

Or if you want some more type safety:

```
static IQueryable<TSource> ToMyData<TSource>(this DbContext dbContext)
     where TSource : IPersonData
{
    IQueryable<TSource> sourceData = dbContext.Set<TSource>();
    if (sourceData == null) throw new ...

    return sourceData.ToMyData();
}
```

Usage would by:

```
IQueryable<Student> studentData = myDbContext.ToMyData<Student>();
IQueryable<Teacher> teacherData = myDbContext.TyMyData<Teacher>();
```

**But my StudentDataBaseEntities is not derived from DbContext!**

In that case you'll have to create a function similar to DbContext.Set. You know exactly which entities your StudentDataBaseEntities supports.

In your StudentDataBaseEntities.

```
public IQueryable<TSource> GetTable<TSource>()
     where TSource : IPersonData
{
    return this.GetTable(typeof(TSource))
}

public IQueryable<TSource> GetTable(System.Type type)
{
     if (type == typeof(Teacher)) return this.Teachers;
     else if (type == typeof(Student)) return this.Students;
     ...

     // TODO: improve this code by using a switch statement
     // TODO: search stackoverflow how to do this for a type
}
```